# Jquery - Display a class when the button is clicked and then deleted

Tags: jquery, event-listener

jquery - Display a class when the button is clicked and then deleted
I would like that if the user clicks on one of the two buttons, the class appears and then if he clicks it again, the class disappears. And this, for each click, not just once.
I can't use the toggle because I have several buttons, I've already tested it and it's not the behaviour I want.
I have tried several codes. I would like that when my buttons `( $('#search-form-menu-label, #language-switcher-label'))` are open, a class appears, and when they are closed, the class disappears. Thank you very much in advance for your help

```
  $('.sticky-navigation').hide('freeze-header');

  $('#search-form-menu-label, #language-switcher-label').click(function() {
    $('.sticky-navigation').addClass('freeze-header');    
  });
```

or

```
  if ($('#search-form-menu-label, #language-switcher-label').is(':visible') {
    $('.sticky-navigation').addClass('freeze-header');
  }
  else {
    $('.sticky-navigation').removeClass('freeze-header');

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the action of checking the visible status attached to something, and it sounds like on click is what you're looking for;

```
  $("#button_click").on("click", function () {
      if ($('#search-form-menu-label, #language-switcher-label').is(':visible') {
    $('.sticky-navigation').addClass('freeze-header');
  }
  else {
    $('.sticky-navigation').removeClass('freeze-header');

  }
  });
```